# How Generic Types Are Instantiated

Tags: c#, generics

I was going through C# Complete reference book by Herbert Schildt. He says, regarding generics, that

> there will be only one version of a generic class that handles all
>   cases in which the type argument is a reference type. This is because
>   the size (in bytes) of all references is the same. Thus, only one
>   version is needed to handle all types of references. This optimization
>   also reduces code-bloat.

Can someone explain why so that there is only one version of the generic class for all the reference types ? How does C# manages with only one version ? For example: in case of value types, the book says, that C# creates a separate class for `Generic<int>` and `Generic<double>`. So, why does it not create separate class for `Generic<MyClass>` and `Generic<AnotherClass>` ? What has not-creating-seperate class for generic reference types to do with the size of class (as mentioned in the text) ?

Comment: Why so what? Why did they implement this optimization? Why does it work? Something else in the text you don't understand?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Apologies, If you did not get what I am asking. I updated the question

Comment: It is not the size of the class that matters, but the size of the variable that holds the class.

Comment: Schildt is well-known for writing programming books that are riddled with errors. The adjective that best describes his books on C and C++ is "garbage". I'm not sure if he's bothered to learn enough about C# to make this book more worthwhile, but caveat emptor. Either way, it doesn't sound like you are at the point in *your* understanding of C# that you need to worry about these types of "under the hood" optimizations. For now, focus on understanding the difference between value types and reference types.

Comment: @CodyGray: although Schildt has a reputation for sloppiness (to the point of having inspired the term "Bullschildt"), there's nothing wrong with this particular statement, and while advanced material, it's a fair question. Indeed, understanding why the compiler can perform this optimization can be done in the context of learning the difference between value and reference types.

Comment: The quotation isn't outright *wrong*, but it is sloppily worded so as to make it very confusing. It being "advanced" was my sole point; I wasn't trying to say that this was a bad question.

Comment: I would echo the comments above; get a better book.  C# in Depth, Essential C#, Effective C#, C# in a Nutshell, and The C# Programming Language are all excellent books. Full disclosure: I edited all of them.

Comment: The wording is clumsy.  There is only one copy of the *machine code*, the product of the just-in-time compiler.  This is possible because at runtime the representation of an object reference is the same for any reference type.  It is just a pointer, it has a fixed size and common operations.  The C# compiler has already checked that usage of that pointer is type-safe for all possible types, so what the pointer points to is not important.  There is a fair bit of help built into the CLR to make the operations identical, generic code is not as optimal.

Comment: @EricLippert: do they *all* contain the nitty gritty on the implementation of generics or are you just racking up the royalties by recommending them all? :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: They don't all get into the implementation details. I have heard that Richter's book is the best for that, but I have not read it myself so I can't give a personal recommendation. My point is just that there are plenty of better C# books out there for everyone from the beginner to the advanced programmer. The only book I get a royalty on is Essential C#, and believe me, it's not exactly funding my retirement. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, as I noted in a comment: get a better book.

Second, you need to understand how code is generated for generics. The C# compiler generates IL -- an "intermediate language" -- for each generic class, and that IL is, like the original source code, truly generic. At runtime, the jitter (the "just in time" compiler) generates *machine code* for each method that you call; it translates the IL into code for whatever machine you're running on.

Suppose you have a generic class with a method:

```
class C<T> 
{
  public static T[] One(T item) 
  {
    return new T[] { item };
  }
}
```

Notice that this method is known to be type safe no matter what T is at runtime.

When you call `C<string>.One("hello");` the jitter generates code that creates an array of one string reference, copies the given string reference into the first place in the array, and returns a reference to the array.

Now suppose you call `C<string>.One("goodbye")`. The jitter doesn't need to regenerate the code, because it already has the machine code in memory.

Now if you call `C<Task<Giraffe>>.One(giraffeTask)`, the jitter *again* does not need to regenerate the code because it already has a method in memory that creates an array of one *reference-sized thing*, copies the *reference* in `item` to the array, and returns a reference to the array. Nowhere -- except the T[] creation -- did the method use the fact that T was actually a string or actually a task that produces giraffes.  If we ensure that the array constructor *also* does not take advantage of knowing what the type is -- and why should it? -- then we can get away with re-using the generated code.

But we can't get away with re-using the code generated for `C<int>.One` when `C<double>.One` is called, because the first copies a 4 byte integer into the array; the second copies an 8 byte double. The jitter can do a better job of optimizing the code by taking the extra space to make two slightly different versions of the machine code.

This optimization is an implementation detail, but it is one of those details that is helpful to know because it gives you a good mental model of how the feature works, why it works that way, and how it differs from similar features in different languages. Java (with erasure) and C++ (with templates) are both subtly different from C# with its true runtime generic type system, and that causes both semantic and performance differences.

Comment: CodyGray: Do not use "while" in technical content as a marker for two parallel thoughts; it is too easy to confuse it with *actual parallelism*. "while" should be reserved for situations in which one thing is actually happening *while* another is happening, to avoid confusion. Use semis to indicate parallel thoughts.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point. I use "while" all the time as a conjunction to express contrast. The possible confusion had never occurred to me, but I certainly see what you mean. I'll try to remember to use a semicolon instead. I think "whereas" would have also worked here.

Comment: Your lucid style of answer was a delight to read. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the quoted text is not quite accurate. The author seems to be trying to explain that the *code* of the class is required to exist only once, for reference types. It is *not* true that you literally get only one copy of the class.

For value types, the storage required for elements of the given type parameter in the class may be different from type to type, because variables of value types are where the data is actually stored. This means that the generic code has to be recompiled for each value type used, to ensure that the correct storage sizes are used.

For reference types, the storage required is just a reference. The actual data is stored elsewhere (i.e. in the heap), and the size of a reference is the same regardless of the type. So one version of the code suffices.

It is in this sense that the quoted text is correct.

But: generic types still remain aware of their type parameters, and the runtime still does runtime type checking on values. In addition, a class with static fields will require new instances of those fields for each combination of type parameters used for that class. So I would not say that it's literally true that *"there will be only one version"* of a generic class, even for reference types.

Comment: Can I safely assume that for all reference types, the placeholder, in case of generics, is System.Object ?

Comment: @SimpleGuy The type used is `System.__Canon`.

Comment: Conceptually, you can imagine it that way. But in reality, the storage isn't really typed at all in the usual sense. The type-checking is either explicit in the code (e.g. you pass an `object` value to the generic class, which in turn has an explicit cast), or it's a non-visible placeholder that doesn't need type-checking (because it's already been safely type-checked at compile-time). See the previous comment above from @Iridium